# Python pjsua - How to create a custom message?

Tags: python, sip, pjsip, python-sip

I'm using pjsua python module, and I don't know how to create a custom message like below:

```
mY'0E@@b,%+&KEEPALIVE sip:user@192.168.0.10 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.10;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPjgdQdo8azxxwRZ9aCVJy5Wdr27fTgDBUy
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:user@192.168.0.10>;tag=w0na7ZUHDVaB8QG38EGdH5f23W3fzKL6
To: <sip:server@192.168.0.10>
Contact: <sip:server@192.168.0.10>
Call-ID: -TtcAtmNnJM5uteQDgMmddoWx7IM1fDP
CSeq: 1 KEEPALIVE
Applier-ID: 24598
Expires: 2147483647
User-Agent: PU/1.0.0
Content-Length:  0
```

Obs: The server and client are in the same PC.

Exists any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What is this KEEPALIVE message? Is it defined in any standard?

Comment: No, yotomy the server application gets this custom KEEPALIVE for know if the client is alive. I can't change this standard because is a old legacy system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but you may be able to do this by using the `py_pjsua` module:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Py_PJSUA

[`pjsua_call_send_request`](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga2bc70969ec7b6c7a63e9f220cd7110d8): Send arbitrary request with the call.
This is useful for example to send INFO request. Note that
application should not use this function to send requests which
would change the invite session's state, such as re-INVITE, UPDATE,
PRACK, and BYE.

A [message on the PJSIP mailing list](http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2008-January/001221.html) addresses a similar case, and indicates that the `on_call_tsx_state()` callback can be used to watch for the response.

This seems to match your requirement, as I assume that the KEEPALIVE does not change the session state. See [documentation here](http://www.pjsip.org/pjsip/docs/html/group__PJSUA__LIB__CALL.htm#ga2bc70969ec7b6c7a63e9f220cd7110d8).

Comment: Thank you, but I think the function send_request will use "Cseq: 'number' INFO", and I can't change INFO for another word but I will test, thank you again.

Comment: I would expect the contents of the second argument to pjsua_call_send_request (labeled "method") to properly influence the CSeq, but I have not tried it.

Comment: Thank you yotommy, I can use the method for send "KEEPALIVE", thanks.